# Using solidity smart contracts in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can I use Solidity smart contracts in hyperledger fabric? If so, how? I could not find any proper way to use solidity smart contracts in hyperledger network

Comment: Though Asad has already answered the links, but I believe this would help you as well https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-smart-contract-on-hyperledger-fabric-3d50f25e577b

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check Hyperledger Burrow and Fabric Chaincode EVM.

https://www.hyperledger.org/use/hyperledger-burrow
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-evm